# Help with ReportViewer

Tags: .net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am trying to add multiple pages to my report.  For example, I have a report that has a first page that is an introduction, then a second page with a set of graphs, then a third page that pulls text from a db, etc.

I have a Report.rdlc, that defines a layout, but it appears to be only one 8 1/2 x 11 page.  In my webform.aspx, I have the report viewer.  I can put the text and charts for the first page layout in the Report.rdlc, but how do I define the layout for Page 2, 3, etc.

I am fairly new to the ReportViewer.  I have read a lot of documentation but I must be missing something as I do not understand how different layouts on different pages work.

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you add a tablix or rectangle or chart or whatever you are using to the report, you can set the `PageBreak` property to tell the report where a new page begins.

When you are designing the report, it may look onscreen like just one big page, but when the report is rendered, the page breaks you set will split it into multiple pages.

Comment: Ok, I saw that, but I was unsure.  So right now I have a page that is 8 1/2x11.  You are saying, make it as long as it needs to be, i.e. 8 1/2x36, and set the page breaks where I need... is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you do not manually specify page breaks, then the report will create them automatically, but probably not where you want.

Comment: But how do I specify page breaks on text objects?  I could only find a way to set page breaks on images.

Comment: Place the text inside a rectangle first and set the page break on the rectangle.